# How to set session time in Auraphp's AuthFactory?

Tags: php, auraphp

I've tried to set the session cookies in Aura [AuthFactory](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Auth) in multiple places over the last few months. I can't seem to find the right place, and I can't find a single bit of documentation how to set the session timeout.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
public function newResumeService(
    AdapterInterface $adapter = null,
    $idle_ttl = 1440,
    $expire_ttl = 14400
) {
```

https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Auth/blob/624fc819c7f329f8a269a219cfabe252573005a2/src/AuthFactory.php#L137-L138

this?

Comment: I just found that yesterday, but I found something dealing with "expired time" a few months ago and it didn't work. And since this was "resume," I was searching for a variable/parameter related to the initial `newLoginService($pdoAdapter)` that gets called. Or some kind of INI setting somewhere.

I've been trying to figure this out off & on for the last year ... even tried to reach out to one of the developers (who never returned my email). 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No ... that didn't do it ... I still get logged out after about an hour of inactivity no matter what I put in that parameter.

Comment: I probably missed your question. So what do you have in your php.ini  `gc_maxlifetime` and `cookie_lifetime` ?

Comment: I think changing `gc_maxlifetime` in the php.ini solved it. I guess it was overriding the code. Maybe it took both changes to work?